# New Laptop - Disc Usage and RAM Consumption Through the Roof

Tags: laptop, memory, disc

I just bought a new laptop:

1. Intel i7 7500U
2. 8GB of RAM
3. 128GB SSD
4. 1T HDD
5. Windows 10

My problem is that out of the blue without any application running it starts making a noise like it is under a heavy load and the disc usage goes through the roof. Also the RAM usage is over 3GB.

[image]

Then suddenly it stops and the disc usage goes down.

The following pictures are when I only have Firefox with one tab open.

[image]
[image]
[image]

As you see both disc usage and RAM consumption values are not normal. Far from it. What is happening? Is there something wrong with the laptop? This can't be normal, can it?

Comment: If you "Open resource Monitor" (see your photos), you will be able to look at what files are actually being written in the disk usage section tagged with the application name. This will indicate what files are being written. Big active times without lots of transfer might be indexing or antivirus(?)

Answer (score 3):

This is absolutely and completely normal.

Modern operating systems go out of their way to use as much RAM as possible since the alternative is wasting it. You can't use 6GB today so you can use 10GB tomorrow. Any RAM not used now is capacity forever wasted. Modern systems leave RAM unused only when they have absolutely no other choice.

If you're thinking "I want RAM free now so I can use it later", that's nonsense. You can use RAM now *and* use it later. There's no trade-off here and no benefit to RAM being unused.

Disks can be maxed out by any I/O-limited task. Typical I/O limited tasks include indexing, defragmentation, and scanning for viruses.

You should investigate where the disk usage is coming from. But right now, you have no reason to suspect anything abnormal is occurring or that anything is wrong.